# Why these two decorators return different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I am new to python decorator. Pls help me. The first output is desired. I don't understand why the second and third decorators decorate "p" "i" "b" tags twice.

```
def AddTags(*tags):
    def decorator(oldFunc):
        def inside(*args, **kwargs):
            code = oldFunc(*args, **kwargs)
            for tag in reversed(tags):
                code = "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(tag, code)
            return code
        return inside
    return decorator

@AddTags("p", "i", "b")
def MyWebWelcome(name):
    return "Welcome "+name+" To my blog!"

MyWebWelcome("Drags")

# Wrong Usage
AddTags("p", "i", "b")(MyWebWelcome)("Drags")

# Wrong
def decorator(oldFunc):
    def inside(*args, **kwargs):
        code = oldFunc(*args, **kwargs)
        for tag in reversed(["p", "i", "b"]):
            code = "<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(tag, code)
        return code
    return inside


decorator(MyWebWelcome)("Drags")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because at the points of using:

```
AddTags("p", "i", "b")(MyWebWelcome)("Drags")
```

or

```
decorator(MyWebWelcome)("Drags")
```

`MyWebWelcome` function is **already** decorated with `@AddTags("p", "i", "b")`. 
`@decorator` form is applied on function ***declaration*** time.
Thus, the 2nd and 3rd call will add another layer of same decoration (wrapping a string with "p","i","b" tags twice)